# How to retrieve a form value, perform an operation on that and display within a <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a number from a form-control type = "number", compare it, and then if OK with the condition, perform multiplication, and division on it. After that I want to display the result as the contents of a `<p>` tag. How to accomplish this?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
let amount = document.getElementById(".amount");
let marginAmount = document.getElementById(".marginAmount")
let submit = document.getElementById(".submit");
submit.addEventListener('click', calcAmount);

const calcLevel1 = amount * 7 / 100;

function calcAmount() {
  let userAmount = Number(amount.value);
  let level1 = 351;
  if (userAmount <= level1) {
    marginAmount.textContent = calcLevel1.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <label for="points amount">Entrez un montant en points</label>
  <input type="number" class="amount-enter" id="amount">
  <input type="submit" value="Montant marge additionnelle" id="submit" class="submit-enter">
</div>
<p id="marginAmount" class="enter-margin"></p>
```

Comment: Typo close - you have `.` in an ID selector.

Comment: Also you need to add .value to amount and marginAmount

Comment: @Dblaze47 Please **do not translate** non-English questions ([meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/3082296)). "*They need to be able to respond to feedback, and if they cannot themselves translate a question we cannot be certain that they can understand any feedback provided by comments, answers, or Help Center content*". If the question is in [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) or [Japanese](https://jp.stackoverflow.com/),  you can refer them to these respective Stack Overflow versions.

Comment: @adiga I was not aware of that. Thanks a lot for the correct suggestion and guiding me in the right direction. Will keep the advice in mind for future reference. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code corrected, there are. Which are to be deleted
I also added `math.round` to get rounded result:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function calcAmount() {
      let userAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
      let level1 = 351;
      if (userAmount <= level1) {
        document.getElementById("marginAmount").textContent = Math.round(userAmount * 7) / 100;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("marginAmount").textContent = "Amount is > 351";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <label for="points amount">Entrez un montant en points</label>
    <input type="number" class="amount-enter" id="amount">
    <input type="submit" value="Montant marge additionnelle" id="submit" class="submit-enter" onclick="calcAmount()">
  </div>
  <p id="marginAmount" class="enter-margin"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

- You had `.` in your ID selectors, these shouldn't be there (they should be `#` but only in a `querySelector` method).
- You were calculating `calcLevel1` straightaway, which meant it was `0 * 7 / 100` which is `0`.
- You needed to calculate `calcLevel1` with `amount.value`, which means you can remove `calcLevel1.value` when you're setting the `textContent` of the paragraph.

I also added an `else` statement so the `textContent` is emptied when the statement is false.

```js
let amount = document.getElementById("amount");
let marginAmount = document.getElementById("marginAmount")
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.addEventListener('click', calcAmount);

function calcAmount() {
  const calcLevel1 = amount.value * 7 / 100;
  let userAmount = Number(amount.value);
  let level1 = 351;
  if (userAmount <= level1) {
    marginAmount.textContent = calcLevel1;
  } else {
    marginAmount.textConten = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <label for="points amount">Entrez un montant en points</label>
  <input type="number" class="amount-enter" id="amount">
  <input type="submit" value="Montant marge additionnelle" id="submit" class="submit-enter">
</div>
<p id="marginAmount" class="enter-margin"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! You really give me a precious help because i'm a beginner and it's not easy to assemblate code with scattered informations. You are a cool man, too!